# Entity Framework with Sql Views in it appear as table in generate .sql file

Tags: sql, entity-framework, model, view

I have an entity model in my project that contains some SQL Views - the views where imported using the "Update model from database" option.

Now when I choose "generate database from model" I see those Views as Tables instead. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct behavior. EF has no idea what was the SQL code defining the view and because of that it can't create it. Moreover EF doesn't care about the way you created your current model so if you first define your model from DB containing views and then create database from that model it will indeed replace all views by tables.

Comment: It may do that but this is wrong behavior. It could remember the model came from a view and at least have an option to not generate a table when generating a database script. I have to delete such definitions every time when creating a new test database so I can compare my database is still in sync to what my models were generated from.

Comment: I definitely agree that it's annoying. I think the way around it though is to just have a create-views script that you run before you run your generated schema creation script. The script will error on the views but keep going.